# Using the same SELECT statement in two different DELETE statements

Tags: postgresql

How can I factor out the common SELECT statement in the following function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_comment(cid integer[]) AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM comment_tree_path
    WHERE descendant IN (SELECT descendant 
                         FROM comment_tree_path 
                         WHERE ancestor = ANY(cid));
    DELETE FROM comment 
    WHERE comment_id IN (SELECT descendant 
                         FROM comment_tree_path 
                         WHERE ancestor = ANY(cid));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SELECT array_agg(...) INTO` to pull the list of targets into a local array variable, then pass that as a parameter to your `DELETE`s using `= ANY`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_comment(IN cid integer[])
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
        descendants_to_delete integer[];
begin
        select array_agg(descendant) into descendants_to_delete
        from comment_tree_path where ancestor = ANY(cid);

        delete from comment_tree_path
        where descendant = ANY(descendants_to_delete);
        delete from comment
        where comment_id = ANY(descendants_to_delete);
end;
$procedure$
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation about `array_agg`?

Comment: Okay, here it is: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a CTE:

```
WITH 
  descendants AS
  ( SELECT descendant 
    FROM comment_tree_path 
    WHERE ancestor = ANY(cid)
  ),
  del_ctp AS
  ( DELETE FROM comment_tree_path
    WHERE descendant IN (TABLE descendants)
  )
DELETE FROM comment 
WHERE comment_id IN (TABLE descendants) ;
```